# No links working on IOS Build of Cordova App

Tags: xcode, cordova, html-framework-7

I have built an App with Framework7 and Apache Cordova, all seems to work fine on Android(emulator and device) also on browser but on iPhone emulator and device no links work, I'm using the Framework 7 router/navigation, I'm thinking the problem lies there. Links just do nothing but if if I addClass on click that works. I tried running a building a basic app and had the same issue and also downloaded the kitchen sink example from the Framework 7 site and tried that and it also had the same issue.

UPDATE: Tried to build a simple app using a new css framework(onsen) initally it worked when all of my pages were in one index.html file but once I broke it out into separate html files it stopped working on the iPhone emulator. Links to other html files just don't work for me?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from Framework 7 Forum

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Added to config.xml